# openpyxl with cx_freeze, json files missing

Tags: json, constants, py2exe, cx-freeze, openpyxl

I am using cx_freeze to create a .exe file which accesses the openpyxl module. However when the application tries to import openpyxl it crashes, with the following error:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\....\exe.win-amd64-3.4\library.zip\openpyxl\.constants.json'

I have looked around online however some of the answers are too complicated to understand the fix. Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give us your setup.py file and a list of all of your imports.

Comment: setup.py file: import cx_Freeze

executables=[cx_Freeze.Executable("GUI_Phast_Results_Generator.py")]

cx_Freeze.setup(name="GUI_Phast_Results_Generator.py",version="1.0", options={"build_exe":{"packages":["xlrd","decimal","openpyxl","openpyxl.styles","re","sip","PyQt4.QtCore","os","sys","random","time"],"include_files":["LOGO_RGB-01.png"],"zip_includes":[]}}, executables=executables)

Comment: imports used by script: import sys, os, ctypes, socket, getpass
import time,
from functools import partial, 
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import xlrd,
import openpyxl,
from openpyxl.styles import Color, PatternFill,
import os,
import re,
from decimal import Decimal,

Comment: I should add that the application was running fine until I added the openpyxl module to it. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: It looks like openpyxl doesn't like being loaded from a zip file, which is what happens in a frozen application. The only fix I know of is to modify the code in openpyxl to look for that data file elsewhere. See http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files

Comment: Thanks Thomas, So I should add my constants.json file as an included file and and add the def find_data_file(filename):
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # The application is frozen
        datadir = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        # The application is not frozen
        # Change this bit to match where you store your data files:
        datadir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

    return os.path.join(datadir, filename) somewhere in the openpyxl code itself? My next question will be where abouts in openpyxl do I paste that code?

Comment: @ThomasK I think it could work if you added 1 of the small files it's missing like when using shelve module you need to  add the db file to your setup.py file and when using pygame you need to add the TrueTypeFontFile to the setup.py file beacause cx_Freeze only goes soo far into the module contents when adding content, so if you need more you have to tell it what exactly is missing.

Comment: @DeeliriousSyntax I tried adding openpyxl to the file list for setup.py. However the constants.json file was not imported. Do you have a script for how to include that in the correct file location?

Comment: @DeliriousSyntax but in this case, even if you add that file to `include_files`, it will be looking in the wrong place for it. It's trying to open() a location that's not actually a filesystem file, because it's inside `library.zip`.

Comment: @ThomasK alright, I think I understand.

Comment: Do I use the following code in the setup.py module or does it go somewhere else? cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#using-data-files

Comment: @ThomasK
Did you ever solve the problem, I am having the exact same issue; the conversation suddenly just ended .. ?

Comment: There were some changes in cx_Freeze 5.0 which should avoid the kind of problem this question was originally about. I no longer follow cx_Freeze closely, though.